# java syntax for anonymous interface implementing anonymous functions

Tags: java, lambda, interface

I have an interface that looks like

```
public interface ListAbstractor
{
    List<String> getList();
    void addTo(String s);
}
```

I want to use it for unit tests on get/set/verify operations on a class with several `List<String> get_xxxx` and `void addToList(String)` functions. I would LIKE to declare it with the minimal amount of verbage (I'm ocd that way).

I've seen [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6) where interfaces (with one method) are implemented in a lovely one line lambda:

```
interface IntegerMath {
    int operation(int a, int b);   
}

...
IntegerMath addition = (a, b) -> a + b;
```

I want to implement it something like:

```
ListAbstractor la  = 
                new ListAbstractor()
                {
                    getList = ()-> settings.getZooKeeperList();
                    addTo = (s)-> settings.addToZookeeperList(s);
                };
```

but eclipse does not like this. So what is the short'n'sweetest way to do this?

Comment: There isn't. Lambda syntax only works with functional interfaces. Use the anonymous class declaration syntax (or define a named type that implements the interface).

Comment: what do you mean by "functional interface"? an interface with a single function?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html

Comment: so then "yes, an interface with a single function"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common solution is to create a special static method in your interface to construct the instances:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public interface ListAbstractor {
    List<String> getList();
    void addTo(String s);

    public static ListAbstractor of(Supplier<List<String>> listSupplier,
                                    Consumer<String> adder) {
        return new ListAbstractor() {
            @Override
            public List<String> getList() {
                return listSupplier.get();
            }

            @Override
            public void addTo(String s) {
                adder.accept(s);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

No need to create additional functional interfaces as you may reuse standard ones. Somewhat similar approach is implemented in [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) static method.

Now you can write:

```
myTestFunction(ListAbstractor.of(settings::getZooKeeperList, settings::addToZookeeperList));
```

Comment: I selected yours as the answer because it looks like the "proper" way to do it in java. I still wish there was a lighter, more anonymous way to declare the functions but that's java for you I guess.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is breaking the interface in to two interfaces. This actually takes LESS code than what I had wanted to do, so win.

```
myTestFunction(()-> settings.getZooKeeperList(),
                (s)-> settings.addToZookeeperList(s));
```

Comment: Have no idea. The question is clear and interesting. Upvoted.